# Datastore GQL with Datetime functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, gql, gqlquery

I have a Google Cloud Datastore Kind, which has the property DataTime. This property is from the type `DateTime`.

I want to create a GQL statement the will return all the rows before two days. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM `Tracing-V1` WHERE StartTime < DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL -2 DAY);
```

I found [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions) the function of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`and`DATE_ADD`. Unfortunately, the GQL don't recognize those functions.

[image]

I get back the error message:

```
GQL Query error: Unknown function "DATE_ADD".
```

Anyone know why? How should I implement it?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [GQL Reference](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference#unsupported_features_and_behavior_differences_from_mysqlpython_gql), the Cloud Datastore GQL only supports the DATETIME and KEY functions, whose functionalities are described in the [Synthetic literals](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference#synthetic_literals) section.

Alternatively, you could do it programmatically, with any [supported programming language](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries). Here’s an example of how it would look like in python:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from google.cloud import datastore

client = datastore.Client()
now = datetime.now()
now = now.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

the_day_before = now - timedelta(days=2)
query = client.query(kind='Test')

query.add_filter('date', '>', the_day_before)
result = list(query.fetch())
print(result)
```